# Stars and Bars partitioning argument

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) formula states that if your order $h$ hats from a store that sells $k$ kind of hats, then there are ${K+h-1\choose K}$ possibilities of hats that you order. Assuming $h>k$ use a partitioning argument to show that this quantity is equal to $\sum_{r=1}^k{k\choose r}{h+r-1\choose r-1}$.

Comment: You're ordering $K$ hats, correct? Have you tried this with some specific case, say $K=5,h=3$?

Comment: ah yeh it seems to break down if k>h

Comment: Please reformat using MathJax. The question as written is very hard to understand. Also, you use 'h' twice in the first line. Shouldn't one of those be K?

Comment: I have edited the question, as I think that the source that I got the question from was incorrect...